# Subset if string contains

Tags: r, regex

I have vector of strings. Some elements of vector (strings) contain `sp z o.o.`which is acronym of "spółka z ograniczoną odpowiedzialnością".

```
first sp.z.o.o.
second s.a          #should be removed
kpt spółka z ograniczoną odpowiedzialnością #should be removed, it is not acronym
third sp z o o 
fourth PP           #should be removed
fifth sp z o.o.
przedszkole niepubliczne im.janusza korczaka #should be removed
sixth               #should be removed
seventh sp z oo 
eighth LTD.         #should be removed
nineth sp-z-o-o
tenth spzoo
sklep spożywczy na górnych adam kłaptocz #should be removed
elita sp.c. zofia szatkowska, tomasz szatkowski #should be removed
eleventh sp.zo.o
towarzystwo przyjaciół chorych "sądeckie hospicjum" #should be removed
```

I want to subset only those which contain all possible combination of `sp z o.o.` with and without spaces/double spaces, dots, comas and other symbols (such as * | - etc.). For this purpose I tried to use code belowe, but it does not work. 
`sample <- df[grepl("(sp\\.z\\.o\\.o\\.)", df$col_1), ]` 
and also 
`sample <- df[grepl("(sp\\.*z\\.*o\\.*o\\.*)", df$col_1), ]` 
**EDITED**: 
*Ronak Shah* suggested:
`grep('s.*p.*z.*o', x, value = TRUE)` It works, but returns strings which shouldn't be subseted, such as: 
`elita sp.c. zofia szatkowska, tomasz szatkowski` 
 
`"społem" powszechna spółdzielnia spożywców w myśliborzu`

I want to subset strings with different variation of acronym `sp z o.o.` and also to avoid all strings which do not contain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following pattern :

```
sample <- subset(df, grepl('s.*p.*z.*o', col_1))
```

This will select rows when we have `spzoo` in the string irrespective of anything in between.

We can test the regex on a vector.

```
x <- c('first sp.z.o.o.', 'second s.a', 'third sp z o o', 'fourth PP',
       'fifth sp z o.o.', 'sixth', 'seventh sp z oo', 'eighth LTD.', 
       'nineth sp-z-o-o', 'tenth spzoo', 'eleventh sp.zo.o')

grep('s.*p.*z.*o', x, value = TRUE)

#[1] "first sp.z.o.o."  "third sp z o o"   "fifth sp z o.o."  "seventh sp z oo" 
#[5] "nineth sp-z-o-o"  "tenth spzoo"      "eleventh sp.zo.o"
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated dataset we can use

```
sample <- subset(df, grepl('sp.?z.?o.?o', col_1))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but returns much more than I actually need. ```sp z o.o.``` it is acronym of "spółka z ograniczoną odpowiedzialnością". I want to subset strings that contain acronym only i.e. ```sp z o.o.``` and its variations. Moreover, using  ```grep('s.*p.*z.*o', x, value = TRUE)``` function ```grep``` returns strings which shouldn't be subseted, such as: ```elita sp.c. zofia szatkowska, tomasz szatkowski```  and ```"społem" powszechna spółdzielnia spożywców w myśliborzu```

Comment: @HermanCherniaiev Can you define clear rules about which strings should be subsetted and which not? You have mentioned in your post `all possible combination of sp z o.o`, `elita sp.c. zofia szatkowska,` is one such combination.

Comment: Edited, I would be appreciated it if you check it

Comment: @HermanCherniaiev How about `grep('sp.?z.?o.?o', x, value = TRUE)` Can you check if it returns the desired strings?