# Check whether string contains specific abbreviation

Tags: r, regex

This question is a continuation of my previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168224/subset-if-string-contains). I have vector of strings. Some elements of vector (strings) contain specific abbreviation "S.A." and its variation with and without dots and also with multiple spaces.

```
dino polska s.a.
elita sp.c. zofia szatkowska, tomasz szatkowski    #shouldn't be subseted
studio urody "julia" renata kochańska    #shouldn't be subseted
ccc s. a. 
ls airport services sa
restauracja aleksandra odejewska    #shouldn't be subseted
firma handlowa "eden ii" krystyna konowalska    #shouldn't be subseted
auto land polska s a
```

In order to subset strings that met condition (contains "s.a." abbreviation) I used follow code:

```
subset(df, grepl('.s.?.a.?', col_1))
```

Generally it works, but it also subsets strings which do not contain abbreviation. 
I also tried to improve my *regural expresion code*

```
'^.s.?.a.?&'
'^(.s.?.a.?)&'
'\\s+.s.?.a.?'
'\\.s.?.a.?'
```

But it does not work. 
My question is whether exists something like anchor for regular expression to emphasize that I am looking for a separate word/expression rather than a part of it. Abbreviation should be perceived as a separate word rather than a part of word, and something like kochań**SKA** (`.s.?.a.?`) should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
subset(df, grepl('\\bs\\.?\\s*a\\b', col_1))
```

See [regex demo](http://%5Cbs%5C.?%5Cs*a%5Cb)

**Details**

- `\bs` - an `s` letter not preceded with any letter, digit or `_` (since `\b` is a word boundary)
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `a\b` - an `a` letter not followed with any letter, digit or `_`